# Collect numerals at the beginning of the file

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file which contains some numerals, for example,

```
There are 60 nuts and 35 apples,
but only 24 pears.
```

I want to collect these numerals (60, 35, 24) at the beginning of **the same** file, in particular, I want after processing, the file to read

```
read "60"
read "35"
read "24"

There are 60 nuts and 35 apples,
but only 24 pears.
```

How could I do this using one of the text manipulating tolls available in *nix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can script an ed session to edit the file in place:

```
{ 
  echo 0a    # insert text at the beginning of the file
  grep -o '[0-9]\+' nums.txt | sed 's/.*/read "&"/'
  echo ""
  echo .     # end insert mode
  echo w     # save
  echo q     # quit
} | ed nums.txt
```

More succinctly:

```
printf "%s\n" 0a "$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' nums.txt|sed 's/.*/read "&"/')" "" . w q | ed nums.txt
```

Comment: Thanks glenn, it's amazing to see how the old `ed' could do such a good job in place.

Comment: Hi, glenn, sorry to bother, maybe you could help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236335/for-loop-in-makefile-has-no-effect

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

```
egrep -o [0-9]+ input | sed -re 's/([0-9]+)/read "\1"/' > /tmp/foo
cat input >> /tmp/foo 
mv /tmp/foo input
```