# For loop in Makefile has no effect

Tags: shell, makefile, sed, grep, ed

I have a one-line script passed into the `foreach` function in a Makefile, as shown below:

```
flag:
        $(foreach f, $*.txt, printf "%s\n" 0a "$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' $f | sed 's/.*/read \"&\"/')" "" . w q | ed $f)
```

What this script line does could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227131/collect-numerals-at-the-beginning-of-the-file). I am just puzzled why it doesn't work this way, because if I put the line into a separate script and call it from the Makefile like this:

```
flag:
        $(forech f, $*.txt, ./script $f)
```

it works fine.

I also tried the shell `for` loop as follows:

```
flag:
        for f in $*.txt ; do \
          printf "%s\n" 0a "$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' $f | sed 's/.*/read \"&\"/')" "" . w q | ed $f ; \
        done
```

still no luck. I must touch some subtle points of Makefiles, could anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: adding one more `$` before the sequence beginning with `grep`,

```
flag:
        $(foreach f, $*.txt, printf "%s\n" 0a "$$(grep -o '[0-9]\+' $f | sed 's/.*/read \"&\"/')" "" . w q | ed $f)
```

or use the old backticks instead

```
flag:
        $(foreach f, $*.txt, printf "%s\n" 0a "`grep -o '[0-9]\+' $f | sed 's/.*/read \"&\"/'`" "" . w q | ed $f)
```

Answer (score 7):

Both too many and not enough $ signs! This lists the *.txt files - note the $$F:

```
all:
    for F in *.txt ; do \
    echo $$F ; done
```

Comment: I tried your way, removing the `$` before `*.txt` and adding `$` before the two occurrences of the variable `f`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks for enlightening me, Neil. It is indeed a missing `$` caused the trouble.